# It is possible to add a customer into a Magento 1 directly through MySql statement?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer

I just tried, added data into `customer_entity`, `customer_entity_varchar`  and `customer_entity_int` tables but they do not appear in the admin grid, there is another table to take in mind?

Comment: This is not recommended way, not even a process defined by magento. However if you still want to create like this then https://praveenk2014.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/create-customer-in-magento-using-custom-simple-mysql-query/ see this hope it helps.

Comment: I knot it is not recommended but given the circumstances, i have only this option.